# Configuring Oracle dataSource settings on WAS Liberty (WL ) - failure

Tags: oracle, websphere-liberty, ibm-mobilefirst

I am receiving **below exception.** on Liberty console & in browser.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSourceException: FWLSE0194E: MobileFirst Server cannot be started because of failure while getting a connection from data-source bound to resource reference: jdbc/WorklightDS. Make sure the database is up, the credentials are correct and the driver is available for the server. [project worklight]

at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:451)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:138)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]
```

When running/viewing an app (war) on a UAT machine having below configuration.

**Environment**:

> - WL 6.3 EE
> - WAS Liberty Core V8.5.5.4
> - Oracle 11g
> - Windows Server 2012 R2

**worklight.properties**

```
publicWorkLightHostname=localhost
publicWorkLightProtocol=http
publicWorkLightPort=9080

wl.db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.11.1:1529:gmaxem
wl.db.username=WRKLIGHT
wl.db.password=wrklight

wl.reports.db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.11.1:1529:gmaxem
wl.reports.db.username=WLRREPOR
wl.reports.db.password=wlrrepor
```

**Web.xml**

```
  <resource-ref>
      <description>Worklight Server Database</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/WorklightDS</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>    
  </resource-ref>

  <resource-ref>
      <description>Reports Database</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/WorklightReportsDS</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>    
  </resource-ref>
```

**Liberty - server.xml**

```
 <application id="worklight" name="worklight" location="myapp.war" type="war"  context-root="/worklight" >
      <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <privateLibrary id="worklightlib_worklight">
          <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>            
        </privateLibrary>
      </classloader>
    </application>


    <jndiEntry value="9080" jndiName="publicWorkLightPort"/>
    <jndiEntry value="localhost" jndiName="publicWorkLightHostname"/>
    <jndiEntry value="http" jndiName="publicWorkLightProtocol"/>
    <jndiEntry value="10" jndiName="serverSessionTimeout"/>


    <library id="OracleLib">
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/oracle" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>


    <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/AppCenterDS" transactional="false">
            <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
            <properties.oracle driverType="thin" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.11.1:1529:gmaxem" user="WLAPPCENTER" password="wlappcenter"/>
    </dataSource>


    <dataSource  jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"  />            
        <properties.oracle  driverType="thin" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.11.1:1529:gmaxem" user="WRKLIGHT" password="wrklight"   />
    </dataSource>   

     <dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"  />
        <properties.oracle driverType="thin" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.11.1:1529:gmaxem" user="WLRREPOR" password="wlrrepor"  />
    </dataSource>
```

I have also copied:

- jdbc jar (**ojdbc6.jar**) at **Liberty\usr\shared\resources\oracle**
- **worklight-jee-library.jar** at **Liberty\usr\shared\resources\lib**
- **myapp.war** at **Liberty\usr\servers\WorklightServer\apps**

The **apps** folder on Liberty contains only these 3 war files.

- **myapp.war**
- **appcenterconsole.war**
- **applicationcenter.war**

Comment: Its either a typo or error in `server.xml` as you have both datasources using **same** JNDI `jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightDS"`, second one should be different - `jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS"`

Comment: I couldn't understand this, both are using different sources?

Comment: You cannot have 2 data sources in the `server.xml` with the **same** JNDI name. The datasource refering to WLRREPOR  should have `worklight/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS` jndiName.

Comment: Check this page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_oracle_manually.html and try to configure datasource via properties not jdbc url.

Comment: yes both data-sources are different. it was copy/past error made here while posting question. So the second one is worklight/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS

Comment: @AAhad, here too - write the solution as an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

The error message mentions jdbc/WorklightDS, therefore the configuration mistake must be in the `<dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightDS" ...>` element.

You are using the syntax `url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.100.11.1:1529/WRKLIGHT"` which is the syntax for a JDBC URL with a service name, but `WRKLIGHT` is probably not the service name but the SID of your database. (Service names usally include some dots.)

You have two options:

- Use the syntax which references the SID: `url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.11.1:1529:WRKLIGHT"`
- Look up the service name in the file `ORACLE_HOME\network\admin\tnsnames.ora`, and use this service name in the URL, instead of `WRKLIGHT`.

Comment: Oh I see, Let me try this

Comment: No it did not work. I tried url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.11.1:1529:myDBSID"  and also tried with url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.100.11.1:1529/myDBSID"  and url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.100.11.1:1529/WRKLIGHT"  as per this WAS infocenter : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-2-17-0-0

Comment: You also need to use a different jndiName in the second dataSource declaration, as mentioned by [gas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3701228/gas).

Comment: BTW, when applied above changes, it gives: 
"javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found in Worklight platform or project /worklight"

Answer (score 0):

Error in update 2: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE0206E: The project /worklight failed to initialize, because the project database schema for data source jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.11.1:1529:gmaxem is from version N/A, which is not supported by the server from version 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357. Use the MobileFirst ant tasks to upgrade the project database schema. [project worklight

This means that the connection to the database worked but that the tables that are expected to be in the table were not found.

If you install manually, you need to create the schema of the tables.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_config_oracle_DB_manually_for_wladmin.html

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

This issue has been resolved.

Unfortunately my client had not created **WLADMIN** database at all and I was told that it does exists. Plus app center database was having wrong tables created as I mentioned in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836486/wl-app-center-exception-database-is-wrongly-configured).

I was not given privileges to install any db tool to interact/see the databases structure.

**Note: -** The above mentioned configuration is correct and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

might be useful to someone, it should be '/' separator for port name and service name

```
<dataSource beginTranForResultSetScrollingAPIs="true" beginTranForVendorAPIs="false" commitOrRollbackOnCleanup="rollback" connectionManagerRef="default-conn-mgr" isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" jndiName="jdbc/test" transactional="true" type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
<jdbcDriver libraryRef="oracleJDBCJars"/>
<properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@my-host.name.xxx.com:portnumber/service.name.com"  password="xxx" user="test_usr"/>
```