# WL - App Center - Exception - database is wrongly configured

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I installed AppCenter via the installation wizard.

**Environment**:

> - WL 6.3 EE
> - WAS Liberty Core V8.5.5.4
> - Oracle 11g
> - Windows Server 2012 R2

I can see the **server.xml** does have below data-source added for app-center.

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/AppCenterDS" transactional="false">
                <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
                <properties.oracle driverType="thin" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.11.1:1529:gmaxem" user="WLAPPCENTER" password="wlappcenter"/>
            </dataSource>
```

I logged-in as **demo/demo** and it opened the interface as well. But on the console I see below exceptions.

Note: - I have kept my App Center database name as **WLAPPCENTER** (should be fine?)

```
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:56)
[err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1275)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[err] java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 72000, Error Code = 1,017
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:383)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:776)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:432)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:151
)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:89)
[err]   at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:71)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1196)
[err]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.ja
va:1212)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.recordDataBaseInfo(PureMeapData.java:268)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.<init>(PureMeapData.java:172)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.fromDataSource(PureMeapData.java:102)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getJPADBStore(DataStoreFactory.java:46)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:34)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil.getData(DataUtil.java:453)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:63)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.MobileServices.<init>(MobileServices.java:58)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.lifecycle.CreationUtils.createObject(CreationUtils.java:66)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.lifecycle.PrototypeObjectFactory.getInstance(PrototypeObjectFactory.java:45)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceInstance.getInstance(ResourceInstance.java:80)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:48)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationPara
metersHandler.java:54)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMetho
dHandler.java:210)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.ja
va:115)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:9
5)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:56)
[err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1275)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[err] java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLAC0003E: Application Center was unable to access the database. The database is wron
gly configured.
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.getPersistenceUnitName(PureMeapData.java:160)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.<init>(PureMeapData.java:175)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.fromDataSource(PureMeapData.java:102)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getJPADBStore(DataStoreFactory.java:46)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:34)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil.getData(DataUtil.java:453)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:63)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.MobileServices.<init>(MobileServices.java:58)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.lifecycle.CreationUtils.createObject(CreationUtils.java:66)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.lifecycle.PrototypeObjectFactory.getInstance(PrototypeObjectFactory.java:45)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceInstance.getInstance(ResourceInstance.java:80)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:48)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationPara
metersHandler.java:54)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMetho
dHandler.java:210)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.ja
va:115)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:9
5)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:56)
[err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1275)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[ERROR   ] An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to the container.
Unable to open data base.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil.getData:475'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open data base.
        at com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil.getData(DataUtil.java:475)
        at com.ibm.puremeap.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:63)
        at com.ibm.puremeap.services.MobileServices.<init>(MobileServices.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.wink.common.internal.lifecycle.CreationUtils.createObject(CreationUtils.java:66)
        at org.apache.wink.common.internal.lifecycle.PrototypeObjectFactory.getInstance(PrototypeObjectFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceInstance.getInstance(ResourceInstance.java:80)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:48)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationPara
metersHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMetho
dHandler.java:210)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.ja
va:115)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:9
5)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
        at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1275)
        at [internal classes]
        at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
        at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLAC0003E: Application Center was unable to access the database. The database is
 wrongly configured.
        at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.getPersistenceUnitName(PureMeapData.java:160)
        at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.<init>(PureMeapData.java:175)
        at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.fromDataSource(PureMeapData.java:102)
        at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getJPADBStore(DataStoreFactory.java:46)
        at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:34)
        at com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil.getData(DataUtil.java:453)
        ... 62 more
```

Comment: You have this exception: [err] java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 72000, Error Code = 1,017. Can you log to the database with the user name and password provided ?

Comment: I have asked the client to verify the provided credentials. I am not given much rights on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

This issue has been resolved.

Unfortunately my client had created wrongs tables inside the App Center database and that's why it was saying'

> Application Center was unable to access the database. The database is
>   wrongly configured.

I was not given privileges to install any db tool to interact/see the databases structure.